# Rock Paper Scissors game Not Looping

Tags: javascript

My game does not loop as intended. You can understand my intention by reading my simple code. Please help me fix the game so that it will loop five times and on the last round it will display a message to the winner based on the final score.

In every round the game should ask input from the user and compare it with the choice selected by the computer and then decides who won and who lose that particular round.

```js
// initialzing our game with the user's and computer's choice
let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let computerSelection = computerPlay();
let playerSelection = '';
// let gameMsg = []

let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function playerPlay() {
    return playerSelection = prompt("Choose your weapon: Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

}

function computerPlay() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length);
    return choice[random];
}

// Function for a Single round game
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        console.log(`Both player chooses ${playerSelection}. OOPS! It's a tie.`);
    } else if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
            if (computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                computerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Paper covers Rock. You lose! Computer Won.");
            } else {
                playerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Rock smashes Scissors. Hurray! You won.");
            }
        } else if (playerSelection === "Paper") {
            if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
                playerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Paper covers Rock. You won!");
            } else {
                computerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Scissors cut Paper. You lose! Computer Won.");
            }
        } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors") {
            if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
                playerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Scissors cut paper. You won!");
            } else {
                computerScore+= 1;
                console.log("Rock smashes Scissors. You lose! Computer Won.");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Wrong Input!");
        }

}

// Looping through the game five times
function game() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        playerPlay();
        computerPlay();
        if (i == 5) {
            if (playerScore > computerScore) {
                console.log("Congrats! You beat the Computer!!!");
            } else if (playerScore == computerScore) {
                console.log("Nobody wins. It's a tie!");
            } else {
                console.log("Hahahha. The Computer have beaten you. You lose the game!!");
            }
            console.log(playerScore);
            console.log(computerScore);
        } else {
             return playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        }
    }
}

function reset() {
    playerScore = 0;
    computerScore = 0;
}

game();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you exit the function when you call `return`. Just remove it!

```js
// Looping through the game five times
function game() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        // ...
        if (i == 5) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // remove this return
            playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Can i have multiple 'return' keyword in a function for example:

function x() {
  return  y;
  return z;
}

Comment: Yes, you can! But in this case only the first value will be returned.